# Combine to array sorts into one?

Tags: c#, linq

I was wondering if it is possible to combine my sorting code into one ?

I sort my array firstly by enum, then by an id number from lowest to highest.

So my current code looks like this:

```
_entities = _entities.OrderBy(a => a.Priority).ToArray(); //sort by enum
_entities = _entities.OrderBy(a => a.PriorityID).ToArray(); //then sort by id
```

So the enum has:

```
High, Medium,Low
```

And IDs are just integers.

So the end result should be like:

```
High¬
  0 , 1 ,2
Medium¬
  0, 1, 2
Low¬
  0, 1, 2
```

I don't know the syntax to combine these, or if this is as simple as it gets? But it does seem a bit inefficient to be sorting by each property one by one.

Whats the correct way to do ths?

Comment: I think you want to use `.ThenBy`

Comment: When you looked at the documentation for sorting functions, what did you find? Did you try to implement anything?

Comment: _entities.OrderBy().ThenBy()

Comment: @tehhowch my question shows what i tried :) But its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ThenBy`:

```
_entities = _entities.OrderBy(a => a.Priority).ThenBy(a => a.PriorityID).ToArray();
```